# Debugging a connection between VS in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

Below is a piece of code I have been working on for the past couple of days:

```
SqlConnection connectMOBILE = new SqlConnection("Server=OMADB03;Database=MOBILE;Trusted_Connection=True;");
string masterErrorString;

connectMOBILE.Open();

string stringIncorrectPassword = string.Concat(
            "SELECT SERVICE_ID, RESPONSE_DATA, DATE_ENTERED",
            "FROM WS_TRANSACTION",
            "WHERE SERVICE_ID = 'GETUSERTOKENLOGIN'");

SqlCommand commandIncorrectPassword = connectMOBILE.CreateCommand();
commandIncorrectPassword.CommandText = stringIncorrectPassword;
SqlDataReader reader = commandIncorrectPassword.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
     {
         masterErrorString = reader.ToString();
         BOAssistant.WriteLine(masterErrorString);
     }
```

This code is using a class called `BOAssistant` that works like `Console.WriteLine` but instead writes to a log file.

What this code should be doing is collecting the results from my query and placing them in my log file, but when I run this program I get the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'SERVICE_ID'.

There are about 20+ more lines but this is the one that stands out the most. This is my first time writing a program that connects Visual Studio and SQL Server so I am wondering if it is something wrong in the code or I am missing something in my code to establish a stronger connection? What is in the code now is a result of research I have done on the internet. Also when I run the query in SQL Server it works so I know the syntax for query is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you combine your string you get incorrect SQL, because spaces are missing. `string.Concat` creates you this query:

```
SELECT SERVICE_ID, RESPONSE_DATA, DATE_ENTEREDFROM WS_TRANSACTIONWHERE SERVICE_ID = 'GETUSERTOKENLOGIN'
```

which obviously has some missing spaces.

Instead, update your query with spaces:

```
string stringIncorrectPassword = string.Concat(
        "SELECT SERVICE_ID, RESPONSE_DATA, DATE_ENTERED ",    // added space
        "FROM WS_TRANSACTION ",    // added space
        "WHERE SERVICE_ID = 'GETUSERTOKENLOGIN'");
```